# Upcasting и downcasting

Tags: c++

Возник вопрос по поводу следующей особенности языка Си++:

```
Converting a derived-class reference or pointer to a base-class reference or pointer is called upcasting, and it is always allowed for public inheritance without the need for an explicit type cast
```

Я конечно понимаю, что так задумали авторы языка, но почему собственно то, что должно называться downcasting-ом, называется upcasting-ом?
Я имею в виду, к примеру, если ученые возьмут мою ДНК, и на ее основе создадут меня же но с более расширенными возможностями (там четыре руки, или два половых органа, вместо одного), то, на эволюционной ступени, они же будут стоять выше чем я, правильно?
Таким образом, получается рост как бы вверх, а не вниз. Т.е. если идти от этого существа ко мне то это будет Downcasting-ом как раз, а не upcasting-ом.
Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имхо это связано с традиционным отображением иерархий классов - базовый класс отображается вверху, производные ниже его. Это можно интерпретировать как то, что предоставляет базовый класс всегда "лежит на поверхности", и если мы движемся по цепочке иерархии от базового класса к производным, то мы "углубляемся" в особенности производных классов (down-casting), следовательно обратный пусть есть up-casting.

Можно попробовать привести аналогичный пример из генеалогии, родители отображаются вверху, потомки - внизу. Движение от потомков к родителям происходит "вверх".

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, здесь уместнее всего вспомнить генеалогическое дерево: исторически предков чаще всего изображали именно вверху, а "ветви" поколений шли вниз - новые поколения легче дописывать снизу страницы/рулона, а не вверх добавлять листы. Ведь и пишем мы сверху вниз - он начала к концу. А так как в языке тоже имеет место наследование, то это правило распространилось и на него.

Но это мое личное мнение, ибо как-то не встречал точной этимологии этих терминов.

Answer (score 2):

Этимология термина upcast - я думаю имеет корнем не от привычки располагать родительский класс в изображении иерархии сверху, а немного другой.

Вверх/Up имеется ввиду по уровню абстракции. Базовый класс всегда имеет более высокий уровень абстракции.

Answer (score 1):

Представил себе это чудо. Это скорее деградация, и по этому точно вниз :)

приведение вверх, потому что, когда на бумаге рисуют дерево классов, то родительский класс располагают в самом верху (так даже удобнее рисовать, если вся иерархия неизвестна).

Comment: да ладно деградация, у него же шесть рук теперь))